# Smarter way to SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using 2 queries (and more if needed) to check total users (by number of rows returned) that belong to specific user's org by checking if the target ID exist in gene_chain and wonder if there is any way for me to query once instead of what I am currently doing?

Every user has an upline, and can be different from our target ID. The tables don't have any specific column for us to directly refer to find answer and only gene_chain has the specific order of the generation chain for us to find which user(s) have target ID in their gene_chain

| user_id | upline_id | gene_chain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100002 | 100001 | 0,100001 |
| 100003 | 100002 | 0,100001,100002 |
| 100004 | 100002 | 0,100001,100002 |
| 100005 | 100003 | 0,100001,100002,100003 |
| 100006 | 100004 | 0,100001,100002,100004 |
| 100007 | 100006 | 0,100001,100002,100004,100006 |
| 100008 | 100007 | 0,100001,100002,100004,100006,100007 |
| 100009 | 100005 | 0,100001,100002,100003,100005 |
| 100010 | 100005 | 0,100001,100002,100003,100005 |
| 100011 | 100008 | 0,100001,100002,100004,100006,100007,100008 |

Query #1: How many users are under 100002's org

```sql
SELECT 
  DP.team.parent_id AS Upline, 
  DP.users.id AS UserID, 
  DP.users.nickname AS Username, 
  DP.users.email AS Email, 
  DP.users.country AS Country, 
  DP.team.gene_chain, DP.team.gene_num
FROM (DP.team INNER JOIN DP.users ON DP.team.user_id = DP.users.id)
WHERE DP.team.gene_chain LIKE '%100002%';
```

Query #2: How many users are under 100005's org

```sql
SELECT 
  DP.team.parent_id AS Upline,
  DP.users.id AS UserID, 
  DP.users.nickname AS Username, 
  DP.users.email AS Email, 
  DP.users.country AS Country, 
  DP.team.gene_chain, DP.team.gene_num
FROM (DP.team INNER JOIN DP.users ON DP.team.user_id = DP.users.id)
WHERE DP.team.gene_chain LIKE '%100005%';
```

Query 3: This will return the total users under the org of 100002 and 100005. This is why I am still stuck with doing the query individually and curious if there is smarter or faster way to achieve this

```sql
SELECT 
DP.team.parent_id AS Upline, 
DP.users.id AS UserID, 
DP.users.nickname AS Username, 
DP.users.email AS Email, 
DP.users.country AS Country, 
DP.team.gene_chain, 
DP.team.gene_num
FROM (DP.team INNER JOIN DP.users ON DP.team.user_id = DP.users.id)
WHERE DP.team.gene_chain LIKE '%100002%' OR DP.team.gene_chain LIKE '%100005%'
ORDER BY DP.team.gene_chain ASC;
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Could it help to use a `OR` to connect both conditions?

Comment: I find my answer from the rows returned by each query and doing OR will mix up the IDs so currently, I am doing the query separately. Just wondering if there is a smarter and faster way to achieve this.

Comment: Expand your WHERE to include desired gene_chains, and check out GROUP BY. Without sample data it's more work to figure out what you need.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question in text form. Don't use screenshots for important information

Comment: Be careful.  It looks like your logic might be faulty, even in each separate query. `gene_chain LIKE '%100002%';` will also match `1100002` and `1000021` and `1000022`, etc.  If these kinds of values are not possible, you may be ok.  The safer approach is to include the separator in the pattern, which might require slight changes: `gene_chain LIKE '%,100002,%';`  You can look for SQL articles on "comma separated lists" for lots of details.  Provide a description of the guaranteed limitations of a chain identifier, to allow review.

Comment: Good catch @JonArmstrong, that just saved my future self!

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  `SELECT version();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to try (but untested).
It shows the approach that can be used to handle multiple patterns in one query.

For just MySQL 5.7+ and to just count per gene pattern found.

If you want the count per team, adjust the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT list`.

```
SELECT p.pattern
     , COUNT(*) AS n
  FROM DP.team JOIN DP.users ON DP.team.user_id = DP.users.id
  JOIN (
         SELECT '%,100002,%' AS pattern UNION ALL
         SELECT '%,100005,%'
       ) AS p
    ON CONCAT('%,', DP.team.gene_chain, ',%') LIKE p.pattern
 GROUP BY p.pattern
 ORDER BY p.pattern
;
```

and we don't really need to JOIN with users for this:

```
SELECT p.pattern
     , COUNT(*) AS n
  FROM DP.team
  JOIN (
         SELECT '%,100002,%' AS pattern UNION ALL
         SELECT '%,100005,%'
       ) AS p
    ON CONCAT('%,', DP.team.gene_chain, ',%') LIKE p.pattern
 GROUP BY p.pattern
 ORDER BY p.pattern
;
```

The result:

```
+------------+---+
| pattern    | n |
+------------+---+
| %,100002,% | 9 |
| %,100005,% | 2 |
+------------+---+
```

The first query requires MySQL 8.0+ or MariaDB 10.2.2+.
The second query supports those and older versions.

```
-- This returns all the matching rows (to maintain your current result)
-- Plus adds `n` per row indicating the count of rows per matching pattern (chain)
-- I've included a better pattern be sure the right chains are identified.
WITH patterns (pattern) AS (
       SELECT '%,100002,%' UNION ALL
       SELECT '%,100005,%'
     )
SELECT DP.team.parent_id AS Upline
     , DP.users.id AS UserID
     , DP.users.nickname AS Username
     , DP.users.email AS Email
     , DP.users.country AS Country
     , DP.team.gene_chain
     , DP.team.gene_num
     , p.pattern
     , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY p.pattern) AS n
  FROM DP.team JOIN DP.users ON DP.team.user_id = DP.users.id
  JOIN patterns AS p
    ON CONCAT('%,', DP.team.gene_chain, ',%') LIKE p.pattern
 ORDER BY p.pattern
;
```

The result:

```
+--------+--------+----------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------+----------+------------+---+
| Upline | UserID | Username | Email | Country | gene_chain                                  | gene_num | pattern    | n |
+--------+--------+----------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------+----------+------------+---+
| 100005 | 100009 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002,100003,100005               |     NULL | %,100002,% | 9 |
| 100004 | 100006 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002,100004                      |     NULL | %,100002,% | 9 |
| 100002 | 100003 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002                             |     NULL | %,100002,% | 9 |
| 100005 | 100010 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002,100003,100005               |     NULL | %,100002,% | 9 |
| 100007 | 100008 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002,100004,100006,100007        |     NULL | %,100002,% | 9 |
| 100003 | 100005 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002,100003                      |     NULL | %,100002,% | 9 |
| 100008 | 100011 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002,100004,100006,100007,100008 |     NULL | %,100002,% | 9 |
| 100006 | 100007 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002,100004,100006               |     NULL | %,100002,% | 9 |
| 100002 | 100004 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002                             |     NULL | %,100002,% | 9 |
| 100005 | 100010 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002,100003,100005               |     NULL | %,100005,% | 2 |
| 100005 | 100009 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002,100003,100005               |     NULL | %,100005,% | 2 |
+--------+--------+----------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------+----------+------------+---+
```

and to also support MySQL prior to 8.0, etc:

```
SELECT DP.team.parent_id AS Upline
     , DP.users.id AS UserID
     , DP.users.nickname AS Username
     , DP.users.email AS Email
     , DP.users.country AS Country
     , DP.team.gene_chain
     , DP.team.gene_num
     , p.pattern
--   , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY p.pattern) AS n   -- Not supported in 5.7 or before. We would do something else to count.
  FROM DP.team JOIN DP.users ON DP.team.user_id = DP.users.id
  JOIN (
         SELECT '%,100002,%' AS pattern UNION ALL
         SELECT '%,100005,%'
       ) AS p
    ON CONCAT('%,', DP.team.gene_chain, ',%') LIKE p.pattern
 ORDER BY p.pattern
;
```

The result:

```
+--------+--------+----------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------+----------+------------+
| Upline | UserID | Username | Email | Country | gene_chain                                  | gene_num | pattern    |
+--------+--------+----------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------+----------+------------+
| 100005 | 100009 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002,100003,100005               |     NULL | %,100002,% |
| 100004 | 100006 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002,100004                      |     NULL | %,100002,% |
| 100002 | 100003 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002                             |     NULL | %,100002,% |
| 100005 | 100010 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002,100003,100005               |     NULL | %,100002,% |
| 100007 | 100008 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002,100004,100006,100007        |     NULL | %,100002,% |
| 100003 | 100005 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002,100003                      |     NULL | %,100002,% |
| 100008 | 100011 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002,100004,100006,100007,100008 |     NULL | %,100002,% |
| 100006 | 100007 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002,100004,100006               |     NULL | %,100002,% |
| 100002 | 100004 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002                             |     NULL | %,100002,% |
| 100005 | 100009 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002,100003,100005               |     NULL | %,100005,% |
| 100005 | 100010 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL | 0,100001,100002,100003,100005               |     NULL | %,100005,% |
+--------+--------+----------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------+----------+------------+
```

Setup for a test case:

```
CREATE TABLE team (
    id          int  primary key auto_increment
  , user_id     int
  , parent_id   int
  , gene_chain  varchar(100)
  , gene_num    int
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    id        int  primary key
  , nickname  int
  , email     int
  , country   int
);

INSERT INTO users (id) VALUES
  ('100001')
, ('100002')
, ('100003')
, ('100004')
, ('100005')
, ('100006')
, ('100007')
, ('100008')
, ('100009')
, ('100010')
, ('100011')
, ('100012')
, ('100013')
, ('100014')
, ('100015')
;


INSERT INTO team (user_id, parent_id, gene_chain) VALUES
  (100002,   100001,   '0,100001')
, (100003,   100002,   '0,100001,100002')
, (100004,   100002,   '0,100001,100002')
, (100005,   100003,   '0,100001,100002,100003')
, (100006,   100004,   '0,100001,100002,100004')
, (100007,   100006,   '0,100001,100002,100004,100006')
, (100008,   100007,   '0,100001,100002,100004,100006,100007')
, (100009,   100005,   '0,100001,100002,100003,100005')
, (100010,   100005,   '0,100001,100002,100003,100005')
, (100011,   100008,   '0,100001,100002,100004,100006,100007,100008')
;
```

Comment: Second query worked for me - The returned rows is correct but the count command didn't and a little too advanced for me

Comment: @ynnaij I noted that COUNT window function is not supported by MySQL 5.7 or before.  That's why it's commented out in that query.  Could you mention which version you are using?  `SELECT version();`  Also, be sure to include the **exact** result you need.  If you just need a count, and not all the other detail, add that detail.  It's tough to provide complete SQL if the requirement isn't clear.

Comment: I just need the count, version returned '5.7.33-2-log'

Comment: @ynnaij The answer is updated.  The first example will work for MySQL 5.7 or better and returns just the count for each gene pattern found.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you and hope this helps someone else who is as new as myself in future.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  DP.team.parent_id AS Upline,
  DP.users.id AS UserID, 
  DP.users.nickname AS Username, 
  DP.users.email AS Email, 
  DP.users.country AS Country, 
  DP.team.gene_chain, DP.team.gene_num
FROM (DP.team INNER JOIN DP.users ON DP.team.user_id = DP.users.id)
WHERE DP.team.gene_chain IN ('100005','100002', '100001')
ORDER BY DP.team.gene_chain;
```

I think you just need to add order by the column you want to have it ordered by. This way you will get the data from given gene_chain one after another.

Comment: gene_chain shows the generation in order, so a user's upline or boss might not be the target ID we want, so I can only search to see if target ID exists within the gene_chain, example of gene_chain is '0,100001,100002,100004,100006,100007'

Comment: What do you mean by target ID? And what does it mean for targer ID to exist within the gene_chain?

Answer (score 0):

you can just do in that way, if I understood your question correctly:

```
SELECT 
  DP.team.parent_id AS Upline,
  DP.users.id AS UserID, 
  DP.users.nickname AS Username, 
  DP.users.email AS Email, 
  DP.users.country AS Country, 
  DP.team.gene_chain, DP.team.gene_num/*, (DP.team.gene_num - (SELECT DP.team.gene_num FROM DP.team WHERE DP.team.id LIKE '%100002%')) AS downline_gene*/
FROM (DP.team INNER JOIN DP.users ON DP.team.user_id = DP.users.id)
    WHERE DP.team.gene_chain IN ('100005','100002');
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. The OP already wrote that `OR` would mix up the IDs - how does your approach resolve this?

Comment: The challenge is there is no column on tables that can help us directly find the rows or the count() we want, I am using the gene_chain to find if the target ID exist in it, if yes then the returned rows total would be my answer